# If $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is $1{-}1$ and continuous, then $f$ is strictly monotone on $I$.

Tags: real-analysis

> Suppose that $I\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ is nonempty. If $f:I\to\mathbb{R}$ is $1{-}1$ and continuous, then $f$ is strictly monotone on $I$.

The answer in the back of the book$^1$, which I found after writing the following proof, says this is false (no explanation). However, I cannot find an error in my proof or think of a viable counterexample. What am I overlooking?

> Suppose not, and there exists some $x_1,x_2,x_3\in I$ with $x_1<x_2<x_3$ such that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)\geq f(x_3)$, or $f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)\leq f(x_3)$. Without loss of generality, we may assume that $f(x_1)\leq f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)\geq f(x_3)$.
>
> If $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ or $f(x_2)=f(x_3)$ then $f$ would not be $1{-}1$; thus, $f(x_1)<f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)>f(x_3)$. We are left with two possible cases.
>
> *Case 1.* Suppose $f(x_1)<f(x_3)$. Then $f(x_1)<f(x_3)<f(x_2)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists point $x_0\in (x_1, x_2)$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x_3)$ with $x_0\neq x_3$ since $x_3\notin (x_1,x_2)$, a contradiction since $f$ is $1{-}1$.
>
> *Case 2.* Suppose $f(x_1)>f(x_3)$. Then $f(x_3)<f(x_1)<f(x_2)$. By the Intermediate Value Theorem, there exists point $x_0\in (x_2,x_3)$ such that $f(x_0)=f(x_1)$ with $x_0\neq x_1$ since $x_1\notin (x_2,x_3)$, a contradiction since $f$ is $1{-}1$.
>
> If we assume that $f(x_1)\geq f(x_2)$ and $f(x_2)\leq f(x_3)$ we are lead to similar contradictions; thus, $f$ is strictly monotone. $\blacksquare$

1: An Introduction to Analysis by William R. Wade, 4th edition

Comment: That $I$ is an *interval* and not just a nonempty subset of $\mathbb R$ is taken for granted, I assume?

Comment: It is true if $I$ is an interval. Is that a valid assumption? The stated question only tells us that $I$ is a subset. Could $I$ be the rationals?

Comment: @Alex As Hagen hints, the error probably is when you apply the IVT. You might not be working with an interval and so IVT might not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The trick in the text of this exercise that $I$ is not assumed to be an *interval*. Your proof is valid *on an interval*.

But, for example, let $I:=[0,1]\cup[2,3]$ and let $f(x):=\left\{\matrix{x,\ \text{ if }\,x\le 1\\5-x,\ \text{if }\, x\ge 2} \right.$.

Comment: People say that God is in the details, but sometimes I think it's the devil. At least I know it's true for *intervals*! Merci, Berci.